# Bookmark Special Paste, Excel look in same folder

Tags: excel, ms-word, excel-formula, bookmarks, vba

I have a word doc and an excel doc, I have created bookmarks in word and special pasted into excel.....These bookmarks works AS LONG as the files stay in the ORIGINAL location (**example- C:\Documents and Settings\My Documents\New Form**)

BUT

I need to move the documents to different client locations (**example- C:\Documents and Settings\My Documents\client1**)

In excel the cell information reads like this;

`=Word.Document.8|'C:\Documents and Settings\My Documents\NewForm\TestFactFind.doc'!'!Title'`

Is there anything I can put so the excel file will look into its current folder to find the word document instead of a set location?

Comment: you need to use a macro. a macro that will look into a folder and subfolders and find all files with your desired extension. then load/open the one you want - or assign path to bookmarks

Comment: Do I set the macro to run "when the excel doc is opened?

Comment: once you get macro working i think you would be running it only when the path to locations/files change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NON VBA Method**

Yes it is possible for the Excel formula to pick up the value from a file from the same directory where the formula containing files reside. You have to use `INDIRECT()`. However a word of caution. INDIRECT will work only if the destination workbook is open.

Here is an example

Let's say the formula in `Cell B1` in `C:\Book1.xlsx` is

`='C:\Sample\[Sample.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1`

Then put this formula in `Cell C1` for testing it

`=INDIRECT("'" & LEFT(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",$A$1))-1)&"[Sample.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1")`

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about Word bookmarks, but I assume they are the same as Excel hyperlinks (?)

This may or may not be relevant in Word, but in excel you can create a link to any other document using the hyperlink formula. If you use the current directory (folder) as the root, it will go from there.

```
".\" is the current folder
"..\" is the parent folder that the current folder is in
```

So lets say you have an excel sheet with links to 20 Word documents stored in a subfolder called REPORTS (excel to word being the reverse of what you proposed, but it is probably the same the other way around?).
The links in each excel cell would be:

```
=HYPERLINK(".\REPORTS\JAN.DOC","January report")
=HYPERLINK(".\REPORTS\FEB.DOC","February report")
=HYPERLINK(".\REPORTS\MAR.DOC","March report")
etc...
```

A feature I use often is to have the filenames, or part of the filenames, listed in an excel column parellel to the links, and use that cell in the hyperlink filename. Take the following example, and assume it to be range A1:B4 (Line 1 being the column headers "month number" and "link to report").
In this example, I named my word documents MONTHxx.DOC, xx being the month number.

```
MONTH NUMBER         LINK TO REPORT
01                   =HYPERLINK(".\REPORTS\MONTH" & A2 & ".DOC","Report for month " & A2)
02                   =HYPERLINK(".\REPORTS\MONTH" & A3 & ".DOC","Report for month " & A3)
03                   =HYPERLINK(".\REPORTS\MONTH" & A4 & ".DOC","Report for month " & A4)
etc
```

Having the cell at the end in the second part of the hyperlink puts the month number also in the name of the link for the user to see. You can, of course, use any cell there to put a name.

The beauty of this method is that if you have, say, a list of 500 files to link to, and they are all numbered in sequence (like the example), you can just copy-paste the first hyperlink all the way down the column which will instantly give you 500 links to other documents.

Just FYI, the documents do not need to be open already. Clicking the link will open the linked document.

I know this is not what you asked about, but it is fairly close. Hope it helped.